# Grails 2.0.3 multi datasource gorm new instance doesn't save

Tags: grails, datasource

I create one application with multiple datasources.
I use before method in controller to know which datasource use.
I keep prefix of datasource in variable to use it dynamically according to the datasource
When I retrieve in object or list of object there is no problem :
example

```
def P = Person.class
def onePerson = p."${varPrefix}".list().get(0)
```

but when I try to create new object to save it ex :

```
def p = new Person()
p.nom = "jean"
p.renom = "dujardin"
p."${varPrefix}".save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
```

I have an error which said there is no table "Person" in my database

So I try this

```
def p = Person.class
p.nom = "jean"
p.renom = "dujardin"
p."${varPrefix}".save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
```

then I have another error which said Person have no property nom solution: nom, prenom etc..

I do not find any solution in the web. According to grails documentation namespace strategy should work but it doesn't

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue?